# Merge two arrays at a specific index

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

Let's say I have an array called **array1:**

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 5];
```

And I have another called **array2:**

```
var array2 = [3, 4];
```

I want to output the result `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` by inserting **array2** *at index number 2* of **array1.**

How can achieve this in JavaScript?

**EDIT:**

**More things to note:**

- Array mutation in place does not matter, either way would be fine.
- The order of the array elements does not matter, the task at hand is to merge two arrays at a specified index.

Comment: Define ‘elegant,’ and please share your own attempts and explain how those attempts failed.

Comment: @DavidThomas I changed the question to _most efficient_, how is that? I've also included one possible attempt at this as [an answer to my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101140/6368005).

Comment: Efficiency is still pretty nebulous--how are you measuring it? Time complexity is potentially a less ambiguous metric but not without its own problems.

Comment: I understand that, but according to whom? Which JS engine/version/implementation, what machine specs, what test cases, etc?

Comment: @ggorlen thinking about this once more, I realize that efficiency will make this overcomplicated, so I've simply asked for different possible solutions.

Comment: @zipzit by 'at index 2', I mean after index number 1. See [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101140/6368005).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `b`'s elements into [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), which adds a series of arguments at index `i` (the optional argument removal is ignored with `0`). `a` will be modified in place.

```js
const mergeInPlace = (a, b, i=0) => a.splice(i, 0, ...b);

const a = [1, 2, 5];
const b = [3, 4];
mergeInPlace(a, b, 2);
console.log(a);
```

You may add braces to force the function to return `undefined` if you find it misleading to return the mutated argument.

If you want to avoid mutation, spread and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is probably easiest:

```js
const merge = (a, b, i=0) => [...a.slice(0, i), ...b, ...a.slice(i)];

const a = [1, 2, 5];
const b = [3, 4];
console.log(merge(a, b, 2));
```

Comment: This will mutate the array getting passed into the function, `array1` will be the same as `result` after merge which I think is wrong.

Comment: I mention this in my answer. The question doesn't make any restrictions on mutation of parameters though.

Comment: Oh yes, I see you have mentioned it. Even without restrictions I think it is bad practice to do so. Why did you bother returning anything from the `merge` function when you can just do `merge(array1, array2, 2); console.log(array1);` then?

Comment: OP answered their own question and I wanted my function to behave as their example did, in-line, and work with chaining. Yes, mutating parameters is not good practice in all cases, but again, that wasn't mentioned as a constraint for the problem. If efficiency is key and you don't mind mutation, the way to go is to plop `b` in the middle of `a`. JS's builtin `array.sort` is an example of an in place function that both mutates and returns the arg array (it is a prototype function, yes).

Answer (score 9):

I've come up with one possible implementation:

```js
// merge 'b' with 'a' at index 'i'
function merge(a, b, i=0) {
  return a.slice(0, i).concat(b, a.slice(i));
}

var result = merge([1, 2, 5], [3, 4], 2);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think this is actually the most elegant one, since it performs the whole thing in one line and doesn't alter the input arrays.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to mutate the original array you can spread slices out into a new array:

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 5];
var array2 = [3, 4];

function merge(a1, a2, i){
    return [...a1.slice(0,i), ...a2, ...a1.slice(i)]
}

console.log(merge(array1, array2, 2))

// negative indexing too
console.log(merge(array1, array2, -2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is just to order them:

```
array1.concat(array2).sort();
```

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 5],
array2 = [3, 4];

let r = array1.concat(array2).sort();
console.log(r);
```

If the goal is to insert at a certain index:

```
array1.splice(2,0,array2);
array1.flat();
```

```js
    var array1 = [1, 2, 5],
    array2 = [3, 4];
    
    array1.splice(2,0,array2);
    let r = array1.flat();
    console.log(r);
```

As an alternative to that you can use a functional approach. I offer this because I find `.splice` to be an ugly method that mutates the array,is too closely named to `slice`, and doesn't even return the array you're probably looking for.

```
let combineAt = (n, a, b) => 
 a.reduce((ac, cv, ci) => 
  (n === ci) ? 
    (ac.push(b, cv), ac.flat()) : 
    (ac.push(cv), ac), []);

 combineAt(2,array1,array2);
```

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 5],
  array2 = [3, 4];
let combineAt = (n, a, b) => a.reduce((ac, cv, ci) => (n === ci) ? (ac.push(b, cv), ac.flat()) : (ac.push(cv), ac), []);

let r = combineAt(2, array1, array2);

console.log(r);
```